# Using HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler for runtime view access

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpcontext

Is there any potential pitfall for using HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler for runtime view access?

```
public static GetView<T>(T view) where T : IView
{
    return  HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as T;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, as long as you're aware that it can be `null`.